# How to upload photo from a cordova to server?

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, camera

I am making one hybrid app now.
Then, it doesn't go well in realize to upload the image in device gallery.

It is the upload using general FTP and the error scoops out of the PHP side.

[Script sources]

```js
var pictureSource;  
var destinationType;  
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}
function capturePhoto() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 90,
    correctOrientation : true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
function capturePhotoEdit() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 90, 
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation : true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
function getPhoto(source) {
//  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 90,
 navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 90,
    correctOrientation : true, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.upload(
  imageURI, 
  "http://192.168.0.26/android/upload.php", 
  win, 
  fail, 
  options
 );
}

function win(r){
 console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Response = " + r.response.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent.toString()+"\n");
}

function fail(error){
 alert("error :Code = " + error.code);
}
```

[PHP Sources]

```html
<?php
 print_r($_FILES);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/');
?>
```

When the reason why it uses the path so would like to be saved in the Desktop.
If the photo is selected at the gallery and the upload is implemented, then one error which cannot know be formed and the something doesn't occur.

[Logcat Description 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dRjQ.png)

[Logcat Description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKyT.png)

Type was clearly put in the options and it sent.
But the Type value is blank value.

Only File Name(=Image URI) seems to be properly delivered.

How do you have to repair when it is the same as PHP-side problem because I see?

For your reference, path of upload.php is "C:\Apache24\htdocs\android".

I hope to solve this problem. thanks.

Comment: [error] = 1, that means that the filesize is too big: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Besides that, move_uploaded_file() needs the full path to the destination, not just the directory.

Comment: @Bert Thank you for your help. I will try once again.